# Хочу написать бот-переводчик в телеграмм с английского на русский, не понимаю в чем ошибка

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

Использую python-telegram-bot. Перевод текста работает до того момента, как только пишу команду для передачи перевода текста ботом

```
from telegram import Bot
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler
import time

bot = Bot(Token)
updater = Updater(Token)


def translate_message(message, context, update):
    translator = Translator()
    trans_message = translator.translate(message, src='ru', dest='en')
    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
        text=trans_message.text
    )


def wake_up(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(
        chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
        text='''Привет, я бот-переводчик\nВведите фразу для перевода'''
    )
    message = update.message.text
    translate_message(message=message, update=update, context=context)


def main():
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', wake_up))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
    while True:
        time.sleep(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Хотя все работает в таком случае:

````
message = 'Что ты делаешь?'
translator = Translator()
trans_message = translator.translate(message, dest='en')
print(trans_message.text) ```
````

Comment: В том что в вашем случае текст сообщения всегда /start, нужно использовать машину состояний

Comment: Можно подробнее, не совсем понимаю…

Comment: сейчас немного погуглил, FSM вроде как используется только в aiogram

Comment: `next_step_handler` в этой либе, вроде как